# List of tuples for json

Tags: python, json, tuples

I wanted to extract data after parsing, but keep getting `An error occurred: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`.

over here I am parsing the data:

```
content_list = json.loads(content)
```

Then I need to extract few information. The data variable should define a list of tuples where each tuple defines a concept and its score.

Example: `('health', 1.2)`

```
data = content_list[('concept','score')]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: pulling an object from a list is done by integers, example `content_list[0]` for the first element. If you want to refer to it by a string then you can use a dictionary with concept as the key and score as the value.

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example of what might be in content (or content_list), as well as the result that would end up in `data` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

A tuple is not a valid index into a list. Only integers and slices are.

You need to extract the data somehow. Here's a list comprehension:

```
data = [(item['concept'], item['score']) for item in content_list]
```